# Manter dados de uma lista ao rotacionar no Android

Tags: android

Comecei a estudar **Android** e acabei caindo nesse problema.

Criei um `RecyclerView` onde é alimentado por um campo `TextView`, porém toda vez que rotaciono o simulador, os valores são zerados.

Encontrei algumas perguntas no StackOverflow inglês porém não conseguir reproduzir os mesmos resultados no meu app de teste.

Tentei utilizar os seguintes métodos, porém não funciona.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    outState.putStringArrayList("myDataSet", myDataSet);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

E quando tento pegar no `onCreate()` acaba dando crash no app, dizendo que a `List<>` não pode ser nula

```
private ArrayList<String> myDataSet = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Parte que chamo no `onCreate()`

```
if(savedInstanceState != null){
    ArrayList<String> savedMyDataSet = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("myDataSet");
    myDataSet = savedMyDataSet;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não sobrescreva `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState)`. Em vez disso sobrescreva `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`.

Ah, e no seu caso sobrescrever `onRestoreInstanceState()` é desnecessário.

Answer (score 1):

Além das respostas dadas, uma ótima opção é a biblioteca `IcePick`.

Através de `annotations`, você consegue fácilmente definir quais variáveis você quer manter o estado, eliminando o *boilerplate* de salvar todas as suas instancias:

```
class Exemplo extends Activity {
    @State String nome; // Será automaticamente salvo usando essa anotação

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Icepick.restoreInstanceState(this, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Icepick.saveInstanceState(this, outState);
    }
}
```

Você pode conferir como funciona [no repositório oficial](https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick)

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml`, na declaração da sua activity adicione a seguinte linha:

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`

Exemplo:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.activity.MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```