# Refresh no WebView ao rotacionar dispositivo

Tags: java, android, webview

Criei minha aplicação via `WebView`, mas quando rotaciono a tela o site dá *refresh*, ou seja volta para o *login*, meu código:

MainActivity:

```
    package com.sirseni.simpleandroidwebviewexample;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://meulink.com/");

            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return false;
                }

            });

            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        }

        // Use When the user clicks a link from a web page in your WebView
        private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("http://meulink.com/")) {
                    return false;

                }

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Main_Activity:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por padrão, ao girar o telefone o método `onCreate` é chamado novamente e com isso, dados que foram carregados dinamicamente serão perdidos a não ser que você faça um tratamento salvando o estado usando o método `onSaveInstanceState()` em sua `Activity`. Veja abaixo:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    myWebView.saveState(outState);
}
```

Para restaurar o estado no seu `WebView` basta suar o método `restoreState()`. Veja abaixo:

```
WebView myWebView;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
   // aqui verifica que o estado está diferente de null. 
   if (savedInstanceState != null)
      myWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
   else
      myWebView.loadUrl("http://meulink.com/");
}
```

Basicamente é quase a mesma coisa de [manter dados de uma lista ao rotacionar no Android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85920/manter-dados-de-uma-lista-ao-rotacionar-no-android), porém usando `WebView`.

Você pode ler mais detalhes na documentação sobre [como recriar uma atividade](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) e sobre o [ciclo de vida de uma atividade](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=pt-br#Lifecycle).

Para deixar registrado, criei um [arquivo no Gist](https://gist.github.com/cleidimarviana/c269a626f92cefa15c262a6de271d62b) adaptado ao seu código.

Comment: Sou muito novato, nesse caso copio esses scripts e substituo o meu?

Comment: @EvertonGouveia editei a pergunta e inserir um link com um arquivo para adaptar ao seu código. Veja: https://gist.github.com/cleidimarviana/c269a626f92cefa15c262a6de271d62b

Comment: teria como fazer o bloqueio da rotação? com o meu código?

Comment: @EvertonGouveia tem sim: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99115/35406

Comment: @EvertonGouveia conseguiu resolver?! Mais alguma duvida?

Comment: estou tentando aqui #vdc

Comment: já deu certo viu, coloquei um bloqueador de rotação.

Comment: @EvertonGouveia Legal! Mas depois dê uma pesquisada depois! Um tempo atrás o google estava meio que filtrando os apps com tela travada para ficar mais em baixo da lista de busca do play store.